# Excel formula results using countifs formula is returning wrong value

Tags: excel

Hi I'm trying to count the number of cells meeting a certain criteria between a range..When I add the < or > I end up with =O

```
=COUNTIFS('SE1617'!AA:AA,"=087",'SE1617'!AM:AM,"=3",'SE1617'!AN:AN,">=18",'SE1617'!AN:AN,">=33")
```

Comment: I think `">=33"` should be `"<=33"`

Comment: In the formula you can delete "SE1617" AN: AN, "> = 18" because after the formula you have the value "> = 33" for the same range, or the problem is as explained by @Scott Craner.